# How to add index in duplicate div? (javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
  for(x=0;x<$this.listQuestion.length;x++){
    $(".star-wrapper").append('<div class="star"></div>');
  }
}
var x =0;
$(".star").each(function(){
  $(".star").attr("index",x++); 

})
```

1. how to make star with index 1,2,3?
2. now index star is only 2

Comment: You shouldn't make up nonstandard attributes. Use `.data()` to associate custom values with DOM elements.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to make it `1,2,3` instead of `0,1,2`? Either initialize `var x = 1;` or use `++x` so you increment before assigning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".star").attr("index", x++)` assigns the index to *all* the `.star` elements, not the current element of the iteration. You should use `$(this)` instead.

```
var x = 0;
$(".star").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("index",x++); 
});
```

If you want the indexes to start at `1` instead of `0`, change the first line to:

```
var x = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var x=1; x<= $this.listQuestion.length; x++) {
    $(".star-wrapper").append('<div class="star"></div>');
    $(".star").attr("index", x); 
}
```

You can start x as 1, that way the index will be 1,2,3, and x would be in the right index.

Answer (score 0):

```js
for(x=0;x<10;x++){
    $(".star-wrapper").append('<div class="star">111</div>');
  }
$(".star").each(function(index, elements){
  $(this).attr("index",index); 

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="star-wrapper"></div>
```